# How to make inputs behave like React in Angular

Tags: angular

In react when I make an element `<input value={this.valFromStore} />` the input is locked until the store changes. In angular 4 when I make an input I can't seem to get the behavior to match. `<input [ngModel]="valFromStore" />` With this when I type into the input it changes the value of the input. Even if I set the valFromStore as a getter with no setter.

Is there a way for my inputs to be tied to the store then on (ngModel) I can simply update the store and let the changes cascade out like I can in react?

UPDATE: adding example to help clarify. In react i'd expect my input to drop every other key input so the value of `testing` would show up in the input like `etn`. In practice I want the _currentValue to an @input which is read from a store and the handleChange to call something like this.store.dispatch(newValAction).

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'field-type-text',
  templateUrl: './field-type-text.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./field-type-text.component.css']
})
export class FieldTypeTextComponent implements OnInit {
  _currentValue: any;

  constructor() { }

  private counter = 0;
  handleChange(e) {
    if (this.counter++ % 2) this._currentValue += e[e.length - 1]
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

html

`<input type="text" [ngModel]="_currentVal" (ngModelChange)="handleChange($event)" />`

Comment: I've also tried `<input [value]="valFromStore" />` with no luck

Comment: You want a readonly input?

Comment: I think you should not use ngmodel to bind but manually handle your value from ngrx store!

Comment: @AniruddhaDas My parent comp loads from the store. This child comp just has an input. valFromStore remains unchanged in the class but the input display changes to not match.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i want it to change only if the store reducer changes the value. keypress request change through reducer then it trickles down

Comment: I've made an attempt for unidirectional flow. Just check https://stackoverflow.com/q/72911753/148271

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the split use of ngModel for input and event emitting:

```
<input [ngModel]="valFromStore" (ngModelChange)="callStoreChange($event)">
```

In this case 'valFromStore' is a local variable `valFromStore` that is already set up to update when the external store changes, and `callStoreChanges($event)` is a local method that changes the store.

If `valFromStore` is an `@Input valueFromStore` you will need to implement `OnChanges` and `SimpleChanges`. If it's a value from an `Observable` it's likely already set up to update on push.

Side note: Remember that if production AOT builds you will want to call changes to your store service from inside your local component, and not the template.

Comment: @Input currentVal: any; is from a store but the parent component connects to it. ngOnInit does this._currentVal = this.currentVal as i try to keep it locked. So `<input [ngModel]="curVal" (ngModelChange)="some voide fn" I expext typing to not change the input. setInterval(_ => console.log(this.curVal), 200) produces the old value, not what is in the input

Comment: We'll need more information, and a lot more code to really understand what you're actually trying to accomplish. You're "expecting typing not to change the input", which confuses me on what you're actually trying to accomplish. Since you're using an `@Input` you will need to implement `SimpleChanges` as I mentioned to update changes from your store.

Comment: i will look more into simple changes and get back with some more information

Comment: What i want is the <input> to not have its own state and to only show what makes it through the reducers and into my store. I don't like the idea of input having its state that it tells my reducer of. I want the global store to tell the input what it should be showing. It seems that the input just displays what it wants and causally tells the store not caring if it succeeded in updating the state.