# ReRender component is not working in Angular

Tags: angular, input

I'm trying to use unidirectional forms just like in React as I'm used to it. But having hard time with the same in Angular. Look at `onCancel` function in below code.

[To run below code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cb99vm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

TS file

```
import { ApplicationRef, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'John';
  temporaryValue = '';
  
  constructor(private ref:ChangeDetectorRef, private appRef: ApplicationRef) {

  }

  onChange($event) {
    this.temporaryValue = $event.target.value;
  }

  onCancel() {  
    this.ref.detectChanges(); //Doesn't work
    console.log('this.name', this.name);
    console.log('this.temporaryValue', this.temporaryValue);


    this.appRef.tick();  //Doesn't work
    console.log('this.name', this.name);
    console.log('this.temporaryValue', this.temporaryValue);

    // below works. but it is not ideal solution. A blink is visible on screen upon cancel. How about when we have object with many properties?
    let x = this.name;
    this.name = '';
    setTimeout(() => this.name = x);

  }
  onSave() {
    console.log('before=>this.name::::', this.name);
    console.log('before=>this.temporaryValue::::', this.temporaryValue);
    this.name = this.temporaryValue;
    console.log('this.name::::', this.name);
    console.log('this.temporaryValue::::', this.temporaryValue);
  }  
}
```

HTML File

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  <input type="text" [value]="name" (change)="onChange($event)" />
  <button type="button" (click)="onCancel()"> Cancel </button>
  <button type="button" (click)="onSave()"> Save </button>
</p>
```

Comment: Request explaining the downvote please. I will happily try to improve/close question.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use two-way binding like this:

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">
```

```js
savedName = 'John';
name = 'John';

onCancel() {  
  this.name = this.savedName;
}

onSave() {
  this.savedName = this.name;
}
```

2. Or `@ViewChild` (would not recommend for this case):

```html
<input #input type="text" [value]="name">
```

```js
@ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

onCancel() {  
  this.input.nativeElement.value = this.name;
}
```

3. Or use `FormGroup` with `patchValue()` for the `FormControl`.